# Prevent two equal lexer tokens following each other

Tags: antlr4

I have following grammar:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

Number
    : '-'? [0-9]+
    ;

Punctuation
    : [\-.]
    ;

Identifier
    : '.'? [a-zA-Z]+
    ;

Whitespace
    : [ \t]+
      -> skip
    ;

Newline
    : ( '\r' '\n'?
      | '\n'
      )
      -> skip
    ;
```

and following input file:

```
1-2
1 -2

.foo
foo.bar
```

This produces

```
[@0,0:0='1',<Number>,1:0]
[@1,1:2='-2',<Number>,1:1]
[@2,5:5='1',<Number>,2:0]
[@3,7:8='-2',<Number>,2:2]
[@4,13:16='.foo',<Identifier>,4:0]
[@5,19:21='foo',<Identifier>,5:0]
[@6,22:25='.bar',<Identifier>,5:3]
[@7,28:27='<EOF>',<EOF>,6:0]
```

What I need to change that `1-2` will be recognized as Number, Punctuation, Number and `foo.bar` as Identifier, Punctuation, Identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem with [semantic predicates](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md):

```
lexer grammar X86AsmLexer;

Number
    : { _input.LA(-1) < '0' || _input.LA(-1) > '9' }? '-'? [0-9]+
    ;

Punctuation
    : [\-.]
    ;

Identifier
    : { _input.LA(-1) < 'a' || _input.LA(-1) > 'z' }? '.'? [a-zA-Z]+
    ;

Whitespace
    : [ \t]+
      -> skip
    ;

Newline
    : ( '\r' '\n'?
      | '\n'
      )
      -> skip
    ;

LineComment
    : ';' ~[\r\n]*
    ;
```

Now the test file

```
1-2
1 -2
1- 2

.foo
foo.bar
```

is lexed as expected:

```
[@0,0:0='1',<Number>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='-',<Punctuation>,1:1]
[@2,2:2='2',<Number>,1:2]
[@3,5:5='1',<Number>,2:0]
[@4,7:8='-2',<Number>,2:2]
[@5,11:11='1',<Number>,3:0]
[@6,12:12='-',<Punctuation>,3:1]
[@7,14:14='2',<Number>,3:3]
[@8,19:22='.foo',<Identifier>,5:0]
[@9,25:27='foo',<Identifier>,6:0]
[@10,28:28='.',<Punctuation>,6:3]
[@11,29:31='bar',<Identifier>,6:4]
[@12,34:33='<EOF>',<EOF>,7:0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the ANTLR Lexer encounters input that can be matched by multiple lexer rules, it selects the appropriate rule using the following:

- The lexer rule that matches the longest sequence of input characters will be used
- If multiple lexer rules match the same number of input characters, the the rule that occurs first will be used to produce the token.

When the lexer sees the input "-2" it finds that the `Punctuation` rule matches the "-" (1 character), BUT the `Number` rule matches "-2" (two characters), so it will always produce a `Number` token using this lexer grammar.

To deal with this you'll need to break things up a bit and deal with some of the details in parser rules.

You'll also, probably NOT want to handle "punctuation" as a single token, but rather have separate tokens for "-" and ".".  (If you have some other need to identify "punctuation" you can write a parser rule to match any of your punctuation tokens.

To get your Identifier broken into segments and dots, you'll need to remove the '.' from the lexer rule.

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

Digits
    : [0-9]+
    ;

Minus: '-';

Dot: '.';

Identifier
    :  [a-zA-Z]+
    ;

Whitespace
    : [ \t]+
      -> skip
    ;

Newline
    : ( '\r' '\n'?
      | '\n'
      )
      -> skip
    ;
```

// parser rules

```
parser grammar TestParser;
options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

exprs: expr+ EOF;

expr: number Minus number 
    | id 
    | number;

id: Dot? Identifier (Dot Identifier)*;

number: Minus? Digits;

punctuation: Minus | Dot;
```

[image: Parse tree for sample input]

Comment: My question is about a lexer (for syntax coloring), not a parser.

Comment: Also, `-2` should be matched by Number, but not `- 2`, so the whitespace would be important here.

Comment: The ANTLR Lexer is not influenced by previous tokenization so the “-2” in “1-2” will be tokenizaed tha same way as the “-2” in “1 -2”.  Most grammars treat the negative sign as an unwary operator (and consequently a separate token from the number itself).

Comment: Whitespace being a separate token (even is skipped addressed your second comment